# Error with AWS EMR Client: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIGNING_REGION

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services

I'm having a sudden issue with this error when I am running my AWS EMR client on our deployed server. This does not happen locally, and runs fine. Basically, I have an EMR client that I use to build and execute steps as such:

```
class EMRClient(emrClusterId:String) extends LazyLogging{

  val accessKey = ...// access key
  val secretKey = ...//secret key
  val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)
  val REGION = <my region>
  println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Initializing EMR client for clusterId " + emrClusterId + " . The region is " + REGION)
  val emr = AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder
    .standard()
    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
    .withRegion(REGION)
    .build()

def executeHQLStep(s3ScriptPath:String, stepName:String, args:String = ""): AddJobFlowStepsResult= {
    val hqlScriptStep = buildHQLStep(hqlScriptPath, stepName, args)
    val stepSet =  new java.util.HashSet[StepConfig]()
    //stepSet.add(enableDebugging)
    stepSet.add(hqlScriptStep)
    executeJobFlowSteps(stepSet)
  }

  /**
    * Builds a StepConfig to be executed in a job flow for a given .hql file from S3
    * @param hqlScriptPath the location in S3 of the script file containing the script to run
    * @param args optional field for arguments for hive script.
    * @param stepName An identifier to give to EMR to name your Step
    * @return
    */
  private def buildHQLStep(hqlScriptPath:String, stepName:String, args:String= ""): StepConfig = {
    new StepConfig()
      .withName(stepName)
      .withActionOnFailure(ActionOnFailure.CANCEL_AND_WAIT)
      .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newRunHiveScriptStep(hqlScriptPath, args))
  }

  private def executeJobFlowSteps(steps: java.util.Set[StepConfig]): AddJobFlowStepsResult = {
    emr.addJobFlowSteps(new AddJobFlowStepsRequest()
      .withJobFlowId(emrClusterId)
          .withSteps(steps)) // where the error is thrown
      }
}
```

However, when this class is instantiated on the server, none of the `println` statements at the top are visible, my `executeJobFlowSteps` method is called and throws this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIGNING_REGION
>           at com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.executeAddJobFlowSteps(AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.java:439)
>           at com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.addJobFlowSteps(AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.java:421)
>           at emrservices.EMRClient.executeJobFlowSteps(EMRClient.scala:64)
>           at emrservices.EMRClient.executeHQLStep(EMRClient.scala:44)

This project is composed of several projects, and similar issues to mine have said it has to do with their AWS dependencies, but across the board all of the projects have this in the build.sbt's library dependencies: `"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.286"`

Any idea on what the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you are mixing the 1.11.286 version of aws-java-sdk with an older version (1.11.149) of aws-java-sdk-core. The newer client is using a new field added to the core module but since your core module is out of date you are seeing the no such field error. Can you ensure all of your dependencies are in sync with one another?

Comment: Great answer! However, you may want to consider having moved the last sentence to a comment on the question and submitting the rest as your answer. Looking for feedback in the answer itself isn't really the intent of SO.